# Update part of the screen with Direct2D

Tags: directx, viewport, direct2d

I have a viewport with some shapes that I draw by using `Direct2D`. At the moment when I change somehting, for example I set a Rectangle fill from red to green, I first clear the render target and then I draw again all the shapes with the new properties.

Since I know the position and the area of the rectangle I modified, is there a way to clear and re-draw only the area that has been updated insted of re-draw all the thousand shapes I have?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for:

```
IDXGISwapChain1::Present1(
UINT                    SyncInterval,
UINT                    PresentFlags,      
[in] const DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS *pPresentParameters);
```

states that

> An app can use Present1 to optimize presentation by specifying scroll and dirty rectangles.

This information about the modified rectangles is supplied via the *pPresentParameters parameter. For details see:

[DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404522(v=vs.85).aspx)